# Neo4j - traverse nodes in new API, starting from given label

Tags: java, neo4j, iterator, iterable

In Neo4j 2.1, I used code like this:

```
ResourceIterable<Node> it = GlobalGraphOperations.at(db).getAllNodesWithLabel(FOO);
TraversalDescription td = db.traversalDescription().breadthFirst().
  relationships(BAR_REL).uniqueness(Uniqueness.NODE_GLOBAL);
for (Path p : td.traverse(it)) {
  ...
}
```

In Neo4j 2.2, the `getAllNodesWithLabel()` method is deprecated, but I'm not sure how to eliminate it.  The replacement method `db.findNodes(Label)` is close, but it returns an `Iterator` rather than an `Iterable`, and there's no way I can see to start a traversal with an `Iterator` unless I wrap it in a dummy `Iterable` or something.  Anyone have a pointer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are (at least) 2 convenient ways to solve this:

1) As you've mentioned wrap the `Iterator` into an `Iterable`. Neo4j has this aboard out of the box:

```
import org.neo4j.helpers.collection.IteratorUtil;
...
for (Path p : td.traverse(IteratorUtil.asIterable(it))) {
  ...
}
```

2) the `traverse` method also accepts an `Node[]` array (as vararg), so you can e.g. use Guava's [`Iterables.toArray()`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Iterables.html#toArray(java.lang.Iterable,%20java.lang.Class))

I'd prefer 1) due to less memory overhead and it does not include another dependency.

Comment: Excellent, I like the first way too.  Thanks.